# Are there any Typescript definitions for the AngularJS ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am using typescript with ui-router.  Has anyone found any Typescript definitions for this. I looked on definately typed and could see nothing.  Here is what I would like to find an interface file for:

```
$stateProvider
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We are using this *d.ts* for `ui-router`:

Updated link, May - 2015

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts

raw version *(ready for copy/paste)*

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts

UPGRADE Notes:

When I updated `angular-ui-router.d.ts` to the latest (May 2015) version, I also faced few build issues. Solution in a nutshell was

> - angular definition was converted
>
>   - from: **`declare module ng {`**
>   - into: **`declare module angular {`**
> - so update **`angular.d.ts`** to the [latest version](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts)
> - updated all related *(existing)* `d.ts` as well *(angular-animate.d.ts, angular-sanitize.d.ts...)*
> - change all other `(custom)` modules declarations like
>
>   - **`declare module ng.XXX {`** into
>   - **`declare module angular.XXX {`**

With these few steps... all should be working again
*([original](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.d.ts), not working link)*

small code snippet form that resources:

```
// Type definitions for Angular JS 1.1.5+ (ui.router module)
// Project: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
// Definitions by: Michel Salib <https://github.com/michelsalib>
// Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

/// <reference path="../angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

declare module ng.ui {

    interface IState {
    ...
```

The example of usage

```
module MyModule
{
    export class MyStateConfig
    {
        constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider
            , private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider
            ...)
        {
            this.$stateProvider.state(...
```

Comment: @KennethLynne, I fixed the link. It should work again. Thanks sir

Comment: I get loads of errors with this version. Doesn't seem to like the | statements

Comment: @JakeStimpson I upgraded, tested, and described my experience in updated answer. Please, try it.. it should work. Thanks for comment, sir