# Typescript angular properties doesnt exist on value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

So I have this bit of code [image]

As you can see, `module` and `IStateProvider` are underlined red, saying that

> the property does not exist on value of type 'typeof angular'

and

> the property does not exist on value of type 'typeof angular.ui'

What's up with this error?

Comment: *I tried to describe issues which I had with the latest d.ts files around angular and ui-router: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25072946/1679310*

Comment: how bizarre, I will have a go at this!

Comment: @RadimKöhler  unfortunately that didn't help my problem. It's not liking the `|` operator

Answer (score 0):

What editor are your using?  Have you tried adding a reference to the angular.d.ts file?

///

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: lol no....that is a terrible answer because as you pull in the tds next time it will be removed.  Never update auto generated/pulled code