# Typescript Directives error "Property IScope dont exist on type 'IAngularStatic"

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I'm writing a Angular Directive with  typescript to able share a scope item, i create a interface that inherits from ng.IScope, but Visual Studio Code show this warning: **"Property IScope dont exist on type IAngularStatic'**, I am using the angular.d.ts type definition file from definitelytyped.org.

[image: Property IScope dont exist on type 'IAngularStatic'Property IScope dont exist on type 'IAngularStatic']

```
module kingApp.Directives {

export interface IMenuDirective: ng.IScope {

}

export function MenuDirective(): ng.IDirective
{

    return {
        templateUrl: 'shared/menu/menu.html',
        controller: Controllers.Home.HomeController              
    }
}
angular.module("kingApp").directive('menu',MenuDirective);
```

}

How i can share data from scope to my current directive ?

Comment: *I guess (just guess) that in this Q & A is reason why it happens and how to fix it...  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25072929/1679310 ...*

Comment: did you mean to use `extends` ? i.e `IMenuDirective extends ng.IScope ` but where are you using this interface though?

Comment: I'm not using yet, but why raise this error :-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `export interface IMenuDirective: ng.IScope {`. It should be `export interface IMenuDirective extends ng.IScope {`. The compiler error is misleading.